# Python: loop over consecutive characters?

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, character

In Python (specifically Python 3.0 but I don't think it matters), how do I easily write a loop over a sequence of characters having consecutive character codes? I want to do something like this pseudocode:

```
for Ch from 'a' to 'z' inclusive: #
    f(Ch)
```

Example: how about a nice "pythonic" version of the following?

```
def Pangram(Str):
    ''' Returns True if Str contains the whole alphabet, else False '''
    for Ch from 'a' to 'z' inclusive: #
        M[Ch] = False
    for J in range(len(Str)):
        Ch = lower(Str[J])
        if 'a' <= Ch <= 'z':
            M[Ch] = True
    return reduce(and, M['a'] to M['z'] inclusive) #
```

The lines marked # are pseudocode. Of course reduce() is real Python!

Dear wizards (specially old, gray-bearded wizards), perhaps you can tell that my favorite language used to be Pascal.

Answer (score 44):

You have a constant in the string module called `ascii_lowercase`, try that out:

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase
```

Then you can iterate over the characters in that string.

```
>>> for i in ascii_lowercase :
...     f(i)
```

For your pangram question, there is a very simple way to find out if a string contains all the letters of the alphabet. Using ascii_lowercase as before,

```
>>> def pangram(str) :
...     return set(ascii_lowercase).issubset(set(str))
```

Comment: If I also get to be a wizard, I'll live with the beard :)

Comment: You can also use <= to check if sets are subsets: set(ascii_lowercase) <= set(str)

Answer (score 20):

Iterating a constant with all the characters you need is very Pythonic. However if you don't want to import anything and are only working in Unicode, use the built-ins ord() and its inverse chr().

```
for code in range(ord('a'), ord('z') + 1):
     print chr(code)
```

Comment: One more thing: if you want the range to be inclusive, do
>>> for code in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1):
 print unichr(code)

Comment: do not advise against importing from the standard lib

Comment: Exactly what I needed!  The other solutions don't work for ranges of letters determined at runtime.

Comment: This doesn't include 'z'. Needs to be `ord('z') + 1`

Comment: Fixed @stanleyli. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You've got to leave the Pascal-isms behind and learn Python with a fresh perspective.

```
>>> ascii_lowercase
'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
>>> def pangram( source ):
    return all(c in source for c in ascii_lowercase)

>>> pangram('hi mom')
False
>>> pangram(ascii_lowercase)
True
```

By limiting yourself to what Pascal offered, you're missing the things Python offers.

And... try to avoid `reduce`.  It often leads to terrible performance problems.

---

Edit.  Here's another formulation; this one implements set intersection.

```
>>> def pangram( source ):
>>>     notused= [ c for c in ascii_lowercase if c not in source ]
>>>     return len(notused) == 0
```

This one gives you a piece of diagnostic information for determining what letters are missing from a candidate pangram.

Comment: sorry, generator expressions are in 2.4 and up, not 2.3

Comment: @hop: I don't get the comment.  The code change looks fine, but the comment is opaque.

Comment: @s.lott: i wrote in the comment to the change itself that GEs work in 2.3+

Comment: @hop: Got it -- you removed the list comprehension because it is no longer required.

Answer (score 2):

A more abstract answer would be something like:

```
>>> x="asdf"
>>> for i in range(len(x)):
...     print x[i]
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Hacky

```
method_1 = [chr(x) for x in range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)]
print(method_1)
```

#### Neat

```
# this is the recommended method generally 
from string import ascii_lowercase  
method_2 = [x for x in ascii_lowercase]
print(method_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write a function similar to Python's `range`

```
def alpha_range(*args):
  if len(args) == 1:
    start, end, step = ord('a'), ord(args[0]), 1
  elif len(args) == 2:
    start, end, step = ord(args[0]), ord(args[1]), 1
  else:
    start, end, step = ord(args[0]), ord(args[1]), args[2]
  return (chr(i) for i in xrange(start, end, step))
```